# Add attribute to dynamically created element

Tags: jquery

I'm using Embedly to generate thumbnails and video previews from video sites. Here's the code:

```
<ul id="galleryThumb">
  <li id="1"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTcz-etqwKg" class="thumb">Video</a></li>
  <li id="2"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVNTdWbVBgc" class="thumb">Video</a></li>
  <li id="3"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5im0Ssyyus" class="thumb">Video</a></li>
  <li id="4"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCF3ywukQYA" class="thumb">Video</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".thumb").embedly({
        key : 'MY_KEY',
        className: "vidPreview"
    },
    function(oembed, dict) {
        if ( oembed == null)
            return;
        var output = "<a class='embedly' href='#'><img src='"+oembed.thumbnail_url+"' /></a>";
        output += oembed['code'];
        $(dict["node"]).parent().html(output);
    });
});
</script>
```

What it does is it replaces all the video links with thumbnail and a preview of the video. The video is enclosed with

```
<div class="vidPreview">
```

which is dynamically created, and the `vidPreview` is defined in the `className`.

What I want is to add an `ID` attribute to this dynamic element, in which I will also get the `ID` from `<li>` as part of the `ID`. Basically, the final output I want is this:

```
<div id="vidPreview-1" class="vidPreview">
```

In `vidPreview-1` is from the ID of the `<li>`

Comment: Where does the `<div>` come into play?  Is it inserted inside of the `<li>` with the `<a>` and `<img>` inside of it?  Is that what `$(dict["node"]).parent()` refers to?

Comment: @jStiffs All the anchor links inside the list elements will be replace with: `<a class="embedly" href="#"><img ...... /></a><div class="vidPreview"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my working code just in case anyone have the same situation:

```
$(".thumb").embedly({
    key : 'MY_KEY',
    className: "vidPreview"
},
function(oembed, dict) {
    if ( oembed == null) return;
    var test = $(dict["node"]).parent().attr("id");
    var output = "<a class='embedly' href='#'><img src='"+oembed.thumbnail_url+"' /></a>";
    output += oembed['code']; $(dict["node"]).parent().html(output).find("div").attr("id", "vidPreview-" + test);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the neighborhood of `$(dict["node"]).parent()` will be the `<div>` that that you're trying to add an `id` to. You can set the `id` by calling `.setAttribute("id","vidPreview-" + num)`. You can make this call right below the line where you call `.html(output)`. Without seeing a dom fragment from the neighborhood that embedly is manipulating, it's hard to tell exactly what code to tell you to use to navigate to the `<li>` or the `<div>`.

Comment: I finally got it working using the code below. Just would like to ask for opinions if I'm doing it the right way (can't answer yet). `$(".thumb").embedly({
  key : 'MY_KEY',
  className: "vidPreview"
 },
 function(oembed, dict) {
 if ( oembed == null)
 return;
 var test = $(dict["node"]).parent().attr("id");
 //alert (test);
 var output = "<a class='embedly' href='#'><img src='"+oembed.thumbnail_url+"' /></a>";
 output += oembed['code'];
 $(dict["node"]).parent().html(output).find("div").attr("id", "vidPreview-" + test);
 
});
`